# Keyboard shortcut to navigate a website

Tags: cross-browser, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm building a PHP application framework where all pages are created dynamically such as:

- domain.com/1/
- domain.com/2/
- domain.com/3/
- etc...

Now I want to add a support so that users can simply use their keyboard to navigate through the site. (May be pressing <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keyboard keys)

Is that something doable? If so, what do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would definitely need to use JavaScript to capture all of the **keydown** (note, arrow keys will not fire **keypress** event) events.  For instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> would go to the /2 page, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> would go to the /3 page.

I think you'd need a way to map the keypress events to the actual page names.  I'd suggest maintaining a layer of abstraction, such as a mapping file, between keydown event codes and the actual page names so that the keycodes could be customized in the future if needed.

Do a search on this event to get you started.  The example below captures the enter key

```js
   if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       // do stuff
   }
```

Here is the list of keycodes:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

To create events for these keys, I would suggest starting out by creating events for them.  You will need jQuery for this example, although there are ways to accomplish the same in pure JavaScript:

```js
// bind keydown events to the window
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 37) {  
       // left arrow - run your code to change back a page
       alert('left');
    } else if(event.which == '39') {
       // right arrow - run code to move forward a page
       alert('right');
    }
 });
```

Table of key events by browser and keys:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

List of key codes:
http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Comment: How can I just use keyboard's right and left arrow to navigate to pages?

Comment: @Chirag - I edited my answer with the code to get you started.  Good luck.